# php page not redirecting after db updated

Tags: php, mysql, html, web

Hi to all and Happy Thanksgiving!  I am using an HTML form to get an email address, and wrote this little php script to add it to mySql database.  Im trying to redirect the user to an html page letting them know i appreciate it.  however, my php script will update my database, but using (header) as seen below is not working to redirect, it just keeps me on the original html form page... i've done some research and just a little confused, my php script contains no HTML, so thats not the issue...really confused, or just burnt out, please help!   (Note: added ******* to protect my privacy ;>) )

```
    <?php
    $host = "*********";
    $user = "*********";
    $db_name= "********";
    $pass= "********";

    $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

    if (!$con) 
    { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
    } 
    mysql_select_db("******", $con);

    $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO *** (email) VALUE ('$email')";         

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
    } 
    mysql_close($con);
    header('Location: http://www.********.com/thanks.html');


    ?>
```

Thanks everyone, the process flows as such:  user goes to /index.html.  using form tags, i get $name.  When user enters their email address then clicks submit, it launches sendSql.php, which is completely all the code that your seeing. This sendSql.php works and updates my database with the users email, however it just hangs on the original index.html page where they inputted their email in the first place, instead of going to my thanks.html page.  In the browser bar, you can see the sendSql.php appear for a second, then it clears back to the default www.****.com/index.html page.  Heres the html code where i launch sendSql.php:

```
                         <form method="post" action="sendSql.php">
                 <input type="text" value="your@email.com" name="email" />
                 <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                         </form>
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Like "headers already sent" ?

Comment: If there is *any* text that appears before the `header()`, then it will not work.

Comment: Also try adding `exit();` after the header redirect - sometimes a browser will wait for the script to properly exit - although thats very rare these days, but you never know.

Comment: which errors produces? where the script stops?

Comment: You say "it just keeps me on the original html form page", how is this possible if its saving the information to the database? If its only the redirect that's failing shouldn't it show a blank page (or at least an error)? Show more code please

Comment: Also, mysql_ isn't being supported anymore, you should use mysqli_ or pdo if this isn't a legacy application.

Comment: added more to my description, hope it helps, thank you everyone

Comment: A small point, but can you access `http://www.****.com/thanks.html` manually (i.e. just by pointing your browser at it)? It could be that the server is providing the default index page in response to a non-existent URL.

Comment: Lorax made a great point, and as you can see, my php file was in a different directory which caused this insanely dumb problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try a simple html redirect at the end of code where you check if the submit button was used, i.e

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.the-domain-you-want-to-redirect-to.com">
```

Used this a while back, let me know if this worked and if not how did you solve the problem

Comment: omg.....while this method works great Grasshopper, i found what my problem was, and apologize for wasting everyones time.  When i wrote my code ORIGINALLY, i had:                                                      'header' which worked fine to test a redirect BEFORE i made the thanks page.  After i made the thanks page, i edited this php code header statement to use the /thanks.html in my redirect, and wouldnt you know when i ftp'd it to my server, i put the UPDATED version in the wrong folder, so every time i tried to fix it, nothing changed.

Comment: APOLOGIES for last comment if it made no sense, im hyperactive to finally move on to new work on this site.  Please read revised comment as 5 mins was up and i couldn't edit.  using (header) worked perfectly fine.  The problem was when i updated my sendSql.php, then ftp'd it, i was in the wrong directory of my server (just a folder away) So every time i tried to fix it, it did absolutely nothing.  Ill put what i used above for others who have a problem like this, hopefully they can save themselves some time.  BIG THANKS to Lorax who put a server side issue in my head.